# identify unique values of 2 data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, tr

I am working with 2 data frames. I want to a file that outputs rows that appear in data frame 1, but do not appear in data frame 2. Here is sample data:

```
df1:
id    visit
094-1   2
094-2   3
0813-1  11
0813-3  22

df2:
id    visit
094-1   2
094-2   3
0819-2  8
```

This is what I want:

```
df3:
id    visit
0819-2  8
```

I tried this, but it is not working. Can someone please help?

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %in% df2 -> x
df2[!x,]-> df3
```

Comment: probably you are looking for those that appear in dataframe 2 and not in dataframe 1 . Your expected output indicates rows present in df2 and not present in df1.Is that correct?

Comment: `anti_join(df2, df1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
fsetdiff(setDT(df2), setDT(df1))
#      id visit
#1: 0819-2     8
```

Answer (score 2):

In dplyr, there is a function `setdiff` for this:

```
df1 = data.frame(id=c("094-1","094-2","0813-1","0813-3"),visit=c(2,3,11,22))
df2 = data.frame(id=c("094-1","094-2","0819-2"),visit=c(2,3,8))

dplyr::setdiff(df2,df1)
      id visit
1 0819-2     8
```

Or:

```
library(dplyr)
setdiff(df2,df1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`base r` solution using a similar approach to the code included in your question. This solution uses the `%in%` operator but reverses it when used in combination with the `!` operator.

**Data:**

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  id = c("094-1", "094-2", "0813-1", "0813-3"),
  visit = c(2,3,11,22)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  id = c("094-1", "094-2", "0819-2"),
  visit = c(2,3, 8)
)
```

**Code:**

```
df3 <- df2[!df2$id %in% df1$id,]
```

**Output:**

```
df3

#>       id visit
#> 3 0819-2     8
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>